# Validating text input and outputting a 'done' div when input is 5 characters long

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written this code in javascript however I have to make it work using JQuery, I have included both the javascript function and the jquery attempt but i can't figure out what is wrong with my jquery attempt could someone please help me?

Javascript working:

```
function done()
{
    var valid = document.getElementById("text2").value.length;
    if (valid > 5)
    {
        document.getElementById('one').innerHTML += "<div class='done rotateone wiggler'></div>";
        document.getElementById('one').className += "grey";
    }
```

Jquery attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Validates the title field is at least 5 characters long.
    $("#text2").done(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value.length >= 5)
        {
            $("#one").append("<div class='done'></div>");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to execute your function right away? (look at the edit to see why I added the `.blur()` event handler) Well, here is how I'd do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text2').blur(function() { // Listen to the "onblur" event on the element
        if (this.value.length > 5) { // No need for jQuery there
            $('#one')
                .append('<div class="done"></div>')
                .addClass('grey')
        }
    })
})
```

See how I use one call only to the DOM by chaining functions on a single element? That's practical and efficient.

Btw, innerHTML is bad for many reasons (including [performance](http://jsperf.com/fragment-vs-appendchild-vs-innerhtml/6)), prefer `.append()` in jQuery and `.appendChild()` in javascript.

Edit: looks like you want this to activate on the `onblur` event. I edited my code.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly. Just getting into Jquery now so this was a great help.

Comment: See the `.blur(fn)` method? jQuery offers plenty of them like `.click(fn)`, `.focus(fn)`, `.dblclick(fn)`, etc. They're all shortcuts to the `.bind('click', fn)` method.

Comment: I will be looking into these later. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `done()` function and just add small changes to adapt jQuery

```
function done()
{
    var valid = $("#text2").val().length;
    if (valid > 5)
    {
        $('#one').append("<div class='done'></div>");
        $('#one').addClass("grey");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my code and replaced it with this and nothing happens now. I did alter the spelling of class on the addClass part. Am i calling the function in the wrong place as when the javascript version worked i was calling it from the input like this: onblur="done()"